# std::to_string без создания новой строки

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

У меня уже имеется `std::string str`, у которой `str.capacity() >= 1024`(т.е строчка пустая, но память уже выделена).

Мне нужно **дописать в конец этой строчки**(`str.append(...)`) `int, double, const char*, long long` **избежав** при этом **аллокаций**, т.е. чтобы использовалась заранее выделенная память.
Как без танцев с аллокаторами и написанием собственного `to_string` сделать это?

Comment: О, вы тоже осознали никчемность `to_string`?

Comment: Похоже на то...

Comment: Как вариант: Узнать через `std::snprintf(0, 0, ...)` сколько символов нужно под число, добавить место под эти символы через `.resize()`, а потом вызвать `snprintf` еще раз, передав указатель на нужную часть строки.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, другими словами, если хотите эффективно контролировать все в своей программе, то пишите на чистом Си

Comment: @avp + это верное направление :)

Comment: @VTT почему никчёмность-то? Делает ровно то, что должна.

Comment: @alexolut Да, но только то, что она делает, не особо нужно. И сама функция, возвращающая строку менее фундаментальна по отношению к функции, дописывающей в существующую строку. Я имею ввиду, что получить из первой вторую просто так нельзя, а вот из второй первую элементарно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Идеального решения я тут не вижу, но современный `std::string` при аккуратном обращении уже позволяет записывать в него данные напрямую. Воспользовавшись "холостым" прогоном `std::snprintf` можно получить то, что вам нужно

```
std::string str;
...

int i = 42;
double d = 3.1415;
const char *pc = "Hello World";
long long ll = 123;

size_t length = str.length();
size_t extra_length = std::snprintf(NULL, 0, " %d %lf %s %lld", i, d, pc, ll);
str.resize(length + extra_length + 1);
std::snprintf(str.data() + length, extra_length + 1, " %d %lf %s %lld", i, d, pc, ll);
str.resize(length + extra_length);
```

Плата за потенциальное отсутствие перевыделения памяти - двойной прогон `std::snprintf`. Ну и, разумеется, если вы совсем совсем совсем уверены в том, что памяти выделено достаточно, то можно обойтись и без двойного прогона

```
size_t length = str.length();
str.resize(str.capacity());
size_t extra_length = std::snprintf(str.data() + length, str.length() - length, 
  " %d %lf %s %lld", i, d, pc, ll);
str.resize(length + extra_length);
```

Comment: Если вместимость достаточная, то надо ли делать resize до записи данных?

Comment: @Qwertiy Разумеется, надо. Записывать данные в сырую память за пределами текущего размера строки смысла нет. И как вы потом собираетесь сообщать строке правильный размер?

Comment: Да, согласен.Что-то я не учёл, что resize затирает данные.

Comment: Небольшой вопрос по стилю: в C функциях `nullptr` ни-ни, даже если используется C++?

Comment: @alexolut: Нет, никаких проблем с `nullptr` нет. Я просто машинально написал `NULL`.

Comment: Вроде в первом случае можно делать resize сразу до правильного размера, потому что перезаписывать null terminator в std::string нулем [разрешается](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12740403/legal-to-overwrite-stdstrings-null-terminator).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: По вашей ссылке я по-прежнему не вижу гарантии, что этот нулевой терминатор хранится *вместе* с самой строкой. По-прежнему в стандарте на оператор `[]` сказано: "Returns: *(begin() + pos) if pos < size()". Почему такой гарантии на дано для "pos == size()"???

Comment: Похоже, начиная с С++11 должен храниться вместе со строкой: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7554172/2752075 *"Почему такой гарантии на дано для "pos == size()"?"* Не знаю. Сначала подумал, что из-за того, что `str.begin() + str.size()` (он же `str.end()`) нельзя разыменовывать, но [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39521025/2752075) написано, что разыменовывать можно.