# to_string быстрее snprintf(странность компилятора C++ от Microsoft)

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11, g++, c++14

Добивая тему про строчки([std::to_string без создания новой строки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/853411/stdto-string-%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%b7-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8)) внезапно обнаружил, что компилятор C++ от Microsoft(`Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.14.26430 for x86`) генерирует бинарник, в котором `std::to_string` быстрее `snprintf` более чем в 3 раза. 
Пробовал запускать тот же код на ideone.com, onlinegdb.com (т.к. расчитывал, что там стоит g++), где `snprintf` оказалось шустрее примерно в 1.4 раза.
Я понимаю, что всё зависит от реализации стандартной библиотеки разными компиляторами, но такую пропасть я увидеть никак не ожидал. **В чём загвоздка, кто посвящён в детали реализации stl от microsoft(или у меня в коде ошибка?) и объяснит совсем запутавшемуся.**
Вот код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <chrono>
using namespace std;

template<typename Callback>
float getElapsedTime(Callback cb) {
    auto start = chrono::system_clock::now();
    cb();
    auto end = chrono::system_clock::now();
    return chrono::duration_cast<chrono::milliseconds>(end - start).count() / 1000.f;
}

int main() {
    ios::sync_with_stdio(false);
    uint64_t start = 0;
    uint64_t end = 10'000'000;

    cout << "0 .. 10\'000\'000\n";
    cout << "snprintf: " << getElapsedTime([&]() {
        char buffer[1024] = {};
        for (uint64_t i = start; i < end; ++i)
            snprintf(buffer, 1024, "%llu", i);
    }) << "s\n";
    cout << "to_string: " << getElapsedTime([&]() {
        for (uint64_t i = start; i < end; ++i) {
            auto s = to_string(i);
        }
    }) << "s\n";

    start = 999'999'999'995'000'000;
    end = 1'000'000'000'010'000'000;
    cout << "\n999\'999\'999\'995\'000\'000 .. 1\'000\'000\'000\'010\'000\'000\n";
    cout << "snprintf: " << getElapsedTime([&]() {
            char buffer[1024] = {};
            for (uint64_t i = start; i < end; ++i)
                snprintf(buffer, 1024, "%llu", i);
        }) << "s\n";
        cout << "to_string: " << getElapsedTime([&]() {
            for (uint64_t i = start; i < end; ++i) {
                auto s = to_string(i);
            }
        }) << "s\n";    
    cin.get();
}
```

Вывод программы, сгенерированной компилятором microsoft(на домашнем компьютере с Windows 10):

```
0 .. 10'000'000
snprintf: 2.103s
to_string: 0.26s

999'999'999'995'000'000 .. 1'000'000'000'010'000'000
snprintf: 5.26s
to_string: 2.115s
```

Вывод с ideone:

```
0 .. 10'000'000
snprintf: 0.747s
to_string: 0.746s

999'999'999'995'000'000 .. 1'000'000'000'010'000'000
snprintf: 1.389s
to_string: 1.884s
```

Comment: Переводил числа от 999'999'999'990'900'000 до 1'000'000'000'010'000'00, т.к. тогда small string optimization не должно играть роли, и память будет выделяться на куче.

Comment: когда речь заходит про Microsoft, можете забыть абсолютно все, что вы знали про стандарты и общепринятые реализации. Ибо, как сказал один хороший человек, `путь стандартов Microsoft чужд` ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @Kir_Antipov: Эти "пионерские байки" гуляют уже давно, но никакого базиса в реальности не имеют.

Comment: @Kir_Antipov Вы явно [отстали от жизни](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2018/05/07/announcing-msvc-conforms-to-the-c-standard/).

Comment: @AnT лет 15 под ними был весьма серьёзный базис. В том же блоге по ссылке выше можно почитать, какие Авгиевы конюшни пришлось разгребать чтобы начать реализовывать полноценную поддержку новых стандартов vc++

Comment: @VTT, ссылка битая. А по теме предположу, что реализация от Microsoft и то, что to_string шаблон, помогает на Windows работать быстрее.

Comment: @MrBin Ссылка рабочая.

Comment: @VTT товарищ, я же шучу)

Comment: Что-то тут весь код неправильный...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В GCC & Clang, вызов `std::to_string` в конце концов вырождается в `snprintf`, тогда как в MSVC (по крайней мере в 2017) идёт прямой вызов внутренней функции `_Integral_to_string`. Эта функция выполняет обычный цикл, который делит число на 10 и составляет таким образом строку. 
Учитывая тот факт, что `snprintf`, вероятно, имеет схожую реализацию конвертирования числа в строку, получается, что `std::to_string` будет быстрее т.к.:

1. Весь код конвертирования числа встраивается, тогда как `snprintf` вызывается через `call`.
2. `snprintf` вынужден каждый раз разбирать строку форматирования, чтобы понять, что за число (или числа) и как его преобразовывать.

Именно второй пункт, скорее всего, и даёт такую разницу в производительности.

Answer (score 2):

Не оправдывая VC++ :) - есть у меня подозрение, что, помимо платы за универсальность, дело еще и в том, что `snprintf` вызывается, а `to_string` встраивается. Покопайтесь там, у кого GCC под рукой - там `snprintf` случайно не встраивается?...

Для интереса добавлен вот такой простейший код вместо `snprintf` (да, да, я знаю, что для 0 он не сработает :))

```
void hands(char * buffer, uint64_t i)
{
    char * c = buffer;
    while(i) { *c++ = i%10 + '0'; i/=10; }
    for(--c; c > buffer; ++buffer, --c)
    {
        char s = *c;
        *c = *buffer;
        *buffer = s;
    }
}
```

Вызов встроился, и у меня результаты для этого варианта, `snprintf` и `to_string` соответственно около 730, 4830 и 1450 мс. Забавно, что никакие танцы с бубном - типа заставить `s` каждый раз переаллоцировать память - особо на время работы `to_string` не повлияли...

Comment: Видимо, дело действительно во встраивании. Посмотрел ассемблерный код, генерируемый msvc(хотя, я ассемблер почти не знаю), но было явно видно, что snprintf не встраивается(есть инструкция call   _snprintf). А to_string нигде так явно не был вызван, и кода msvc сгенерировал для to_string почти в 4 раза больше. И да, код я подравил, сейчас обновлю вопрос.